# Tool to test the upload performance

Tags: performance-testing

I have to test whether the excel sheet is uploading correctly into a database,example: Oracle etc.Can anyone suggest a tool for the same.

Thank you

Comment: First you should decide what you want to test exactly: performance (upload speed) or success rate (percent of files uploaded to the DB successfully).

Comment: looks out of topics treated on stackoverflow. But please explains more about your context (you got an excel, you got database...)

Comment: I need to import an excel sheet in a database and check its upload speed.